# Ubuntu 17.04 - why is my swap file not being used?

Tags: 17.04, swap

[image]

I think I ran the `swapon` command.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *System Monitor* image you attached, the RAM usage is 89%.

You aren't using the entire RAM of your machine -  hence **there is no need to use swap file on disk**.

Also, it is clear that you have 7.6GB of swap file, 2MB of the file is in use (which is about 0.0001% of total swap file)

Comment: If i use entire ram , swap file will run?

Comment: Yes - The purpose of `swap` file is extend your RAM with a file on disk (which will be 1000 slower than the RAM)